# Imposible to open migrated post by link to original

Tags: bug, android-app, hyperlinks

I just tried to open link from the item 11 from [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/339911):

> [image]

and got an error:

> [image]

Openning [this link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79051/why-was-my-question-moved-and-why-was-it-then-deleted-off-of-the-original-site/79082#79082) from web version of SE is OK.

- App Version: 1.0.89
- Device Manufacturer: LGE
- Device Model: LG-H860
- OS Version: 7.0 (1635123498b3d)

Comment: The API doesn't give out information for deleted posts whatsoever, which includes any that might have been migrated. To the app, it's not a deleted migrated question, it's just a nonexistent question.

Comment: @animuson have any plans to improve API in the recent future?